# Get polymer paper-list selected item value in a form

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

After try and read everything about, I really can't to pass the value of a form that contents a paper-listbox. The code I have is this:

```
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Location" name="page_parent" class="md" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
            <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
                <paper-item value="1">First choice</paper-item>
                <paper-item value="2">Second choice</paper-item>
                <paper-item value="3">Third choice</paper-item>
            </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <input is="iron-input" name="title" type="hidden" value$="[[selected]]">
```

The content of $title value is empty.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html:

> Data binding binds a property or sub-property of a custom element (the host element) to a property or attribute of an element in its local DOM (the child or target element).

This means that the input wont be able to see the properties of the paper-dropdown-menu because:

- The paper-dropdown-menu isn't the parent of the input
- The paper-dropdown-menu and input don't share a parent

To solve this you could create a new custom element so that both share a parent:

```
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <paper-dropdown-menu label="Location" name="page_parent" class="md">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{myChoice}}">
          <paper-item>First choice</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Second choice</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Third choice</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

      <input is="iron-input" bind-value="[[myChoice]]">
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element'
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>


  <my-element></my-element>
</body>
```

paper-dropdown-menu also doesn't have a selected-item-label property

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what MrK is talking about, but you should be able to do like this:

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Location" name="page_parent" class="md">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected={{mySelection}}>
            <paper-item value="1">First choice</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="2">Second choice</paper-item>
            <paper-item value="3">Third choice</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <input is="iron-input" name="title" type="hidden" value$="[[mySelection]]">
```

And dont forget to declare your property:

```
mySelection: {
   type: Number,
   value: 0,
   notify: true
}
```

Now the `paper-dropdown-menu` will default to `First choice` and whenever you change, the value will be reflected to the `mySelection` property, which in turn will change the value if your `iron-input`.